# C: Simple way to input and store string securely in console?

Tags: c, security, memory, input, console

I am creating a console application that would store some sensitive strings in memory, to be sent to the other client. In this case it is almost like a secure messenger (a few% insecurity would be acceptable), although not as complex.

Would accepting user input with (a function to accept one letter at a time for processing purposes such as finding key letters) in to a portion of memory that is allocated be completely unsecure, in terms of not being protected from other processes that may spy?

I am tempted to encode each character before sending it off to the string, although that seems a bit silly. Are there any methods to "lock" access to that malloc (at least to trivial attempts at memory viewing) or similar techniques to secure the string in memory?

Thank you.

I am open to many ideas, currently am just planning.

Comment: I think that - but I may be wrong - in modern system process X can't access memory allocated "for" process Y, unless process X has special privilegies (the same the kernel has); if the kernel is *poisoned*, everything may be unsafe. Moreover a keylogger can read the input before you obfuscate it into your string.

Comment: @Shin, A keylogger could be the magic answer to recording , however there are many "lesser" insecurities that may be there that I am wanting to at least blindly guard against, especially as I am storing plain text in memory. I do like it if it cannot be accessed however as you have stated.

Comment: @Shin: In most OS's (including Windows and Linux), there are API calls for reading memory from another process *(which require administrative privileges, but don't require a kernel-level process)*.  This is how debuggers work.

Comment: @BlueRaja, I had thought so (thank you), luckily I can get away with storing in memory without being plain text so that a debugger would return if not unrecognizable results assumed to be nonsense.

Comment: @BlueRaja I forgot it when wrote this commet... of course debugger worked using some feature that requires just that debugger is run with the same user as the process to be debugged, or root. So at least user account or root/admin account should be compromised, which is a problem of its own that threaten the whole machine

Comment: @Kenny R. once you can fire a debgger on the process, or any other tools, deobfuscating is a matter of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want true security in terms of preventing anyone from seeing what you have stored in memory then encrypting (or at least, obfuscating) each character as you read it is the way to go.  Otherwise there is very little you can do to prevent a determined attacker from viewing your plaintext data in memory.  In fact, I believe the Blu-ray master key was cracked due to a device that loaded an unencrypted representation of the key into its memory.

Comment: but a determined attacker could attach a debugger (s/he already entered the machine as the same user of the running process or as root) to the running program and defeat obfuscation in a small amount of time, if it is worth. If s/he has the executable, he can disassemble it to know the obfuscation algo and apply it to the whole interested memory... i.e., if there's a determined attacker around, even sophisticated protections are defeated, so for small personal programs I would say it is not worth spending time securing them; in this case the weak part, to me, is that it *sends* to other client

Comment: "securing them this way" I mean... I would spend more time thinking about how data are sent and how to make it "safe" to send them to the other end.

Comment: Very wise @ all, maybe I will make a very light on resource usage encryption or storage method that has a random seed, of which is sent encrypted to the other client (or something, I am sure I could come up with a way.) I am not worried about them being on the computer however, so some random password like method would be the most secure for me.